# Blank rows after trailer record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exporting query results from SQL to a pipe delimited file. The file requires a header and trailer record, which I am incorporating into the SQL code. I know this is easier using VS, but have not had time to learn this program yet. I received an error from the vendor that blank rows exist after the trailer record. Is there a way to prevent this using code?

```
set nocount on

select distinct
'HDR' 
,'8.3'
,('00333_UHC_ASMP_DIRECT_'+ (convert (varchar (15), getdate(),112)) +'120000'+'.txt')
,'UHC' 
,'DIRECT' 
,'P' 
,'Y' 
,'' 
,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''

union all

select distinct 
'DTL' as "SEG TYPE"
,pat.pat_last_name "Last Name"
,pat.pat_first_name "First Name"
,isnull(pat.PAT_MIDDLE_NAME, '') "MI"
,Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,pat.BIRTH_DATE,106),101) DOB
,convert(varchar(9), sub.SUBSCR_NUM) "Member ID"
,'' as "SSN"
,(case when pat.SEX_C = '1' then 'F' when pat.sex_c = '2' then 'M' else 'U' end) GENDER
,'' as "STATE CODE"
,'' as "HIC"
,Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,enc.CONTACT_DATE,106),101) FDOS
,Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,enc.CONTACT_DATE,106),101) TDOS
,'' as "BILL TYPE"
,'' as "DISCHARGE"
,'' as "PROV ID"
,ser2.npi NPI
,'' as "PROV TYPE"
,'' as "FACILITY NM"
,nam.last_name "PROV LAST NAME"
,nam.first_name "PROV FIRST NAME"
,'' as "Specialty"
,'' as "TAX ID"
,enc.los_proc_code "CPT"
,'' as "REV CODE"
,'' as "SERVICE FDOS"
,'' as "SERVICE TDOS"
,'11' as "POS"
,'0' as "ICD INDIC"
,'' as "RA Code"
,'' as "Chart Barcode"
,'' as "Chart Enc Key"
,'' as "Chart DX Key"
,'' as "Contract ID"
,pat.ADD_LINE_1 "Mem Street Address"
,isnull(pat.ADD_LINE_2, '') "Mem Street Address 2"
,pat.city "Mem City"
,st.abbr "Mem State"
,pat.zip "Mem ZIP Code"
,'' as "CLAIMID/PCN"
,replace(convert(varchar, icd10.code), '.', '')

 from pat_enc enc

left join patient pat on enc.pat_id = pat.pat_id
left join pat_enc_dx dx on enc.pat_enc_csn_id = dx.pat_enc_csn_id
left join clarity_ser ser on enc.visit_prov_id = ser.prov_id
left join clarity_ser_2 ser2 on ser.prov_id = ser2.prov_id
left join PAT_ACCT_CVG cov on pat.pat_id = cov.PAT_ID
left join coverage sub on cov.coverage_id = sub.coverage_id
left join V_COVERAGE_PAYOR_PLAN b on cov.coverage_id = b.coverage_id
left join cl_emp_ot emp on (ser.[user_id] = emp.[user_id] and (ser.prov_name = emp.USER_NAME_EXT_OT and ser.prov_name = 'STUART, JAMES G')) or (ser.[user_id] = emp.[user_id] and ser.prov_name <> 'STUART, JAMES G')
left join names_static nam on emp.EMP_NAME_RECORD_ID = nam.record_id 
left join zc_state st on pat.state_c = st.state_c
left join zc_sex on pat.sex_c = zc_sex.RCPT_MEM_SEX_C
left join clarity_dep dep on ser2.PRIMARY_DEPT_ID = dep.department_id

left join V_EDG_HX_ICD10  icd10 on dx.dx_id = icd10.DX_ID 
 where b.benefit_plan_name = 'UNITED HEALTH SENIOR CARE' and enc.CONTACT_DATE between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' and enc.los_proc_code is not null and dep.department_name like '%ripcpc%' and icd10.code is not null
 /*order by pat.PAT_LAST_NAME, pat.PAT_FIRST_NAME, FDOS*/
 UNION ALL

 select distinct
'TRL' 
,'00333' 
,'25319' 
,'' 
,'' 
,'' 
,'' 
,'' 
,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
```

Comment: Show us your code! (SELECT statement, T-SQL procedure etc.)

Comment: More a general question of it can be done, but here...

Comment: The blank record appears after or before `TRL` row?

Comment: after. two rows. I believe I can delete them using notepad++

Answer (score 0):

If you want to blank rows not to come after trailer row use Order by. And if you want to remove them try some other way..

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS SNO, ....... ETC
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 2 AS SNO, ....JOIN.... ETC
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 3 AS SNO, .... ETC
ORDER BY SNO
```